# Make a table cell editable by placing input box over td

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I want to make a table cell editable on double click so that I can put some value in cell :

[image]

Currently I am placing a input box inside td on dblclick on it :

```
$('<input type="text" />').val(oldCellval).appendTo($this).end().focus().select();
```

`$this` is my `td` element in which I want to show input box on double click, `On blur` I am removing input box and setting new value back.

I would like to show `input` box **over** td element instead of **inside** it so that it will appear input is inside `td` element, because I am using a table library which only allows text inside `td` elements, on adding html element(`input`) inside td its not working properly. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the benefit of overlapping if you have to update content after edit either way? Would not it be simpler just to replace td with input and after edit replace input with new value ? $(selector).html('html to replace'), will library complain if you recreate original td ?

Comment: replacing html content of td element is creating problem.

Answer (score 3):

For similar result you can use `contenteditable`

```
<table border="3">
<thead>
<tr>Heading 1</tr>
<tr>Heading 2</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td contenteditable='true'></td>
<td contenteditable='true'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td contenteditable='true'></td>
<td contenteditable='true'></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/kpkjr7ev/

Comment: This will permanently add input box to td, i cannot place input box inside td as this is giving me problem, I also cannot add attribute to td element because tds are created by library internally I am only giving data and column names as input to create table.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this,using **[`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable)** attribute that you can avoid input tag

```js
$('td').on({
  'dblclick': function() {
    $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);
  },
  'blur': function() {
    $(this).prop('contenteditable', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>Heading 1</tr>
    <tr>Heading 2</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ddd</td>
      <td>ddd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ddd</td>
      <td>ddd</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/

---

I think you should use this great plugin called **JQuery Datatables**
https://www.datatables.net/

This has a "editable" feature, https://editor.datatables.net/, working great, from where you can also update your MySQL DB :
https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/

You need to dive in and spend some time to master it. Once done it is a great tool for lots of table projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you  set contenteditable='true' in this way 
this will probably not work in IE.
So I recommend you to add a div in td in this way

and in Js on double click of cell make the cell editable

```
 $(this).find('#editdiv').prop('contenteditable', true)
```